# How do I format a number with custom leading characters?

Tags: c#, string-formatting

I need to have a number formatted with certain leading characters. Ideally the code will be obvious so that it can be easily maintained. For example, if you have a number, say an integer of `42` or a currency amount of `$1234.56`, for example, output the following formats:

```
FOO.....42       A customer specified ID number format with leading periods.
$ xxxxxxx42      Format for dollar amounts with leading x's.
$ ~~~~1,234.56   Format for printing checks with leading tilde.
```

This question came about while I was refactoring some ugly Regex code, and I wanted to make it easier for others to modify and maintain.

Comment: how does the number `42` become `1,234.56`?

Comment: @Rufus Thanks -- I'll edit for clarity.

Answer (score 2):

The following string formatting should be easily understood and maintained. Use the `{0,n}` string format for `n` leading spaces, and then `.Replace()` to modify the string after that.

```
var n = 1234;
var c = "FOO";
var d = 1234.56;
var s = string.Format("{0}{1,8}", c, n); // The ",8" denotes up to 8 leading spaces.
Console.WriteLine(s);
s = string.Format("{0}{1,8}", c, n)
    .Replace(' ', '.');          // Change leading space to period.
Console.WriteLine(s);
s = string.Format("$_{0,8}", n)  // Up to 8 leading spaces.
    .Replace(' ', 'x')           // Replace spaces with 'x'.
    .Replace('_', ' ');          // Replace the leading underscore with space.
Console.WriteLine(s);
s = string.Format("$_{0,12:#,#.##}", d) // Decimal format with leading spaces.
    .Replace(' ', '~')           // Replace spaces with '~'
    .Replace('_', ' ');          // Replace the leading underscore with space.
Console.WriteLine(s);
```

Output:

```
FOO    1234
FOO....1234
$ xxxx1234
$ ~~~~1,234.56
```

Comment: FYI, all the `Console.WriteLine("{0}", s);` lines can be simplified to `Console.WriteLine(s);`

Answer (score 2):

You may be interested in the `PadLeft` method, which pads the left part of any string with a number of characters so that the overall string length is equal to the specified length. Obviously it doesn't do anything if the string is already greater than or equal to the specified length.

The following method takes in a string, a prefix, and a character to use as padding between the prefix and the string. It does some initial validation to change null strings to empty strings and to check the string length against the desired length, and then it uses `PadLeft` to pad the string with the specified character:

```
private static string PrefixAndPad(string text, string prefix, char padChar, int length)
{
    text = text ?? "";
    prefix = prefix ?? "";

    if (text.Length >= length) return text;
    if (prefix.Length + text.Length >= length) return prefix + text;

    return prefix + text.PadLeft(length - prefix.Length, padChar);
}
```

You could then use it like:

```
private static void Main()
{
    // Our input strings, which are numbers converted to strins
    string str1 = 42.ToString();

    // The following line formats as currency ("c") then removes the currency symbol
    string str2 = 1234.56.ToString("c").Replace("$", "");

    Console.WriteLine(PrefixAndPad(str1, "FOO", '.', 10));
    Console.WriteLine(PrefixAndPad(str1, "$ ", 'x', 11));
    Console.WriteLine(PrefixAndPad(str2, "$ ", '~', 14));

    Console.Write("\nDone!\nPress any key to exit...");
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

**Output**

[image]

Comment: Nice string extension; this would alleviate any confusion over formatting syntax.